# How do I make rails form responsive to a hyperlink?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

I am following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and have completed the part about creating microposts. I was wondering if anyone have an idea about how to make the micropost form responsive to a hyperlink. For example, when a user types in `"<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>"` in the micropost, I want the link to active. Any help would be appreciated.

**micropost_controller.rb**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy


def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
  if @micropost.save
  flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  @feed_items = []
  render 'static_pages/home'
end
end

def destroy
  @micropost.destroy
  redirect_to root_url
end

private 

  def micropost_params
    params.require(:micropost).permit(:html)
end

def correct_user
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
end
end
```

**micropost.rb**

```
 class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base   
   belongs_to :user  
   default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }   validates :content,
   presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }   validates :user_id,
   presence: true end

 ...
 end
```

**micropost_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`sanitize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) helper method and pass in the anchor (`a`) tag as the only allowable tag.  You don't use it when they create the post, you use it when you are showing the micropost in the view

`app/views/microposts/show.html.erb`

```
<%= sanitize micropost.content, tags: ['a'] %>
```

(I don't know exactly how you are showing the content of a micropost, but this should give you an idea)
This is safer than other options like `html_safe` because you can actually control which html tags you will allow the user to be able to input.